# Excel 2016 Canť even handle all these IFs

Tags: excel

Found a problem which Im not able to solve with my excel "skills" so Im askin for help.

V. Excel 2016

( https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8VLH.png )

https://files.fm/u/nvkgsf63

http://www.filedropper.com/excel4so

I have 3 tables. First is a table with input. Second one is a something I want to add to the first one and third is the output i need to CREATE with functions. 1st and the 2nd table is gonna change every month and so does the output then.

(3rd Table is just and shorten example - added there only IDs 551 and 77 to show what i mean)

Basically what i need is:

If ID number (Example 551) appears in 2nd table and the 1st - do(in CASH) 8768,2 + 892,30 (with HOURS too) and put it into the 3rd table with the same ID.

If ID number does NOT appear in the 2nd table (Example ID 54) - just copy data from the input.

If ID number does NOT appear in the 1st table (Example ID 77) - Add data to the end of the 3rd table.

I hope everything is clear with these examples, if not just ask, ill try to explain it better.

Thank you so much guys

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Excel can handle lots of if() - now more than 7 layers - what usually happens is one can’t follw the logic all the way through. Have you got what you have tried so we can see? Another option may be vlookup or a combination of index() and match()..

Comment: Uploaded. I actually just copied the 1s table and deleted some things to show what i mean. Thats probably my problem - I don't really know all the functions and i might be missing some. Thanks anyway!